# Cоздание объекта класса HWPFDocument

Tags: java

При попытке создания объекта класса, не выходит создать объект класса, ссылаясь на:

> HWPFDocument() has protected access in 'org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument

Что необходимо сделать? Как создать объект класса?

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument();

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Новая папка\\get.doc"))) {
            document.write(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: точно ругается при создании, а не при попытке записать `write` ?

Comment: У класса есть несколько public конструкторов. Все они с параметрами:
HWPFDocument(DirectoryNode directory)
HWPFDocument(java.io.InputStream istream)
HWPFDocument(POIFSFileSystem pfilesystem)
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html#constructor.detail